# Using Python to wait for a specific Serial Input before sending a serial output

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, raspberry-pi

Here's a little background on this project. Im trying to write a script that will run at the startup of the raspberry pi and run continuously as long as the pi is on. The script needs to output a text file over the rs232 port, but only when it receives chr17 (ascii) from a cnc machine. chr17 is also the xon code for software flow control I believe.

So as soon as the machine requests an input, the raspberry pi will output whatever file the script is pointed to. When the machine requests an input it outputs chr17. And when it gets the last line of the file it outputs chr18 to signal it is finished.

As far as the memory on the pi, I don't know the most efficient way of executing this script, I think a while loop might take up too much memory on the pi. I'm not sure though.

If anyone can help me come up with this script that would be very much appreciated.

As of now this code works if i execute it after the machine has requested an input. But i need it to run continuously and then as soon as it sees the machine request an input, it should output the file.

Here's what I have, feel free to modify whatever you need or completely start over if its not helpful, lol.

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=4800, bytesize=7, parity='E')
machinenumber = "BND-2"
cncfile = "/home/pi/myNAS/myShare/e-matix/Machines/%s/Upload/9937.cnc" % machinenumber

try:
    port.open()
except Exception, e:
print "error opening serial port:" + str(e)
if port.isOpen():
    port.write(open(cncfile, "rb").read())
    print ("worked")
    print (open(cncfile, "rb").read())
else:
    print ("cannot open port")
    time.sleep(5)
port.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you running out of memory, or are you asking how to modify that script so it runs indefinitely?

Comment: I guess i could have worded that better. I want to run a script indefinitely, but without hogging the little memory a raspberry pi has.

Answer (score 0):

1) put script in crontab, set so it starts at boot time:

```
@reboot  python /path/to/script.py
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/

2) put above script in a `while` loop, so it runs then starts again

Comment: thank you for your help regarding getting the script to boot at start, but more specifically I'm looking for a way to send serial data only when a specific character (chr17) is received from the machine. So the script will only send data over the serial port when it gets a chr17 from the machine.